# Unable to create google cards for an event

Tags: node.js, email, node-modules, google-now

My requirement is to create a [google card](https://www.google.com/landing/now/#cards) through email using node modules named [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer). Using [google developers](https://developers.google.com/) I found [this](https://developers.google.com/schemas/tutorials/google-now-cards). I created a markup and verified it using [google markup tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/). When I send a mail through [Gmail Actions](http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/) as mentioned the tutorial I am able to create a google card but when I send an email through [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) I am unable to create my Google Card. Can Somebody help as to why I am unable to create `google now card` through [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer)?

My `email` template is as follows:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script type="application/ld+json">
       {  "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "EventReservation",
          "reservationNumber": "E123456789",
          "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
          "underName": {
                   "@type": "Person",
                   "name": "John Smith"
           },
          "reservationFor": {
             "@type": "MusicEvent",
             "name": "Foo Fighters Concert",
             "url": "http://foofighterstour.com/SFO",
             "performer": {
                 "@type": "Person",
                 "name": "The Foo Fighters",
                 "image": "http://www.amprocktv.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/foo-fighters-1-680x383.jpg"
  },
        "startDate": "2015-08-20T16:10:00+05:30",
        "endDate": "2015-08-20T16:20:00+05:30",
        "doorTime": "2015-08-20T16:01:00+05:30",
        "location": {
               "@type": "Place",
               "name": "Random Park",
               "address": {
                   "@type": "PostalAddress",
                   "streetAddress": "1 Random Street",
                   "addressLocality": "New Delhi",
                   "addressRegion": "Delhi",
                   "postalCode": "110001",
                   "addressCountry": "IN"
                }
           }
       },
       "ticketToken": "qrCode:AB34",
       "ticketNumber": "abc123",
       "numSeats": "1",
       "modifiedTime" : "2015-08-20T16:05:00+05:30",
       "modifyReservationUrl" : "http://www.google.com"}
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
    This a test for an Event reservation Google Now card in Gmail.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `Code` in Node JS is as follows:

```
       var fs = require('fs');
       var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
       var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
           service: 'Gmail',
           auth: {
               user: 'xyz@gmail.com',
               pass: '123456'
           }
       });
       fs.readFile('emailTemplatePath', "utf8", function (err, data) {
           var mailOptions = { 
               from:'xyz@gmail.com'             // sender address 
               to: 'xza@gmail.com', // list of receivers 
               subject: 'Booking reservation', // Subject line 
               html: data
           };
           transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
       });
```

Comment: you are receiving mail or not when you sent from nodemailer? And also check Dates within your html, if the time is below the current time, it might not show up in google now

Comment: Hi I am receiving the mail on my gmail account and set the time to today's time and still the google card is not getting generated. Even when I change the date to 2015-08-21T11:30:00+05:30 it is still not generating a google card!!!

Comment: Test emails need to be signed/authenticated with DKIM/SPF signatures as mentioned in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952662/unable-to-test-the-gmail-custom-actions). I also see you're sending from xyz@gmail.com to xza@gmail.com, which won't even work using Apps Script or http://gmail-actions.appspot.com. The "from" and "to" need to be the same in order for it to work. If you have a Google Apps domain, you can register to be whitelisted for internal usage. You can find more info on registering here (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google).

Comment: Franco, is there a way to create Google cards from an email sent from one of to other? Also can you suggest me how to ensure email auth can be done using some npm modules.

Comment: @shubham agiwal you will have to be whitelisted for your non-personal email in order to send to other Gmail accounts. Basically, register with a non Gmail/Yahoo email account, check out their registration page (developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google). I was able to find a past answer  on authenticating with Nodemailer (please see the top answer at this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857681/signing-emails-with-dkim-in-node-js).