# Signing emails with DKIM in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, meteor, dkim

I use the built-in functionality in Meteor.js to send enrollment emails and password reset emails:

- [Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(...)](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-sendEnrollmentEmail)
- [Email.send(...)](https://docs.meteor.com/api/email.html)

Meteor uses MailComposer from NodeMailer to send emails, and this package seems to [support email signing](https://nodemailer.com/dkim/). Can I configure a DKIM private key in Meteor so that my emails get signed?

Answer (score 1):

[Meteor-Mailer](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Mailer) supports DKIM signing out of the box, also with SES.

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SES", {
    AWSAccessKeyID: "AWSACCESSKEY",
    AWSSecretKey: "AWS/Secret/key"
});

// all messages sent with *transport* are signed with the following options
transport.useDKIM({
    domainName: "example.com",
    keySelector: "dkimselector",
    privateKey: fs.readFileSync("private_key.pem")
});

transport.sendMail(...);
```

Original answer in [Signing emails with DKIM in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857681/signing-emails-with-dkim-in-node-js?rq=1)

Please note that [Meteor-Mailer](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Mailer) can have multiple STMP providers and [nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer) also support DKIM signing.

Comment: Can this be used for the built-in enrollment/password reset email feature, i.e. [Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(...)](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-sendEnrollmentEmail)? Meteor hides a bit of the implementation so you don't call a sendMail() function of the underlying library yourself.

Comment: I'll check it during the weekend

Answer (score 0):

The Accounts package does not support providing DKIM keys to node mailer - but - the package uses a common function (**Accounts.generateOptionsForEmail**) to create the object to be mailed, so it is possible to wedge the package to provide this functionality.

```
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base'

//
// Reconfigure Account.base to allow DKIM insertion

const dkim = {
    domainName: Meteor.settings.mail.dkim_domain,
    keySelector: Meteor.settings.mail.dkim_key,
    privateKey: Meteor.settings.mail.dkim_private
}
// Keep a reference to the original "generate" function
Accounts.generateOptionsForEmailPackage = Accounts.generateOptionsForEmail

// Replace the package function with one that adds the DKIM options
Accounts.generateOptionsForEmail = (email, user, url, reason, extra = {}) => {
    const emailParams = Accounts.generateOptionsForEmailPackage(email, user, url, reason, extra)

    // If DKIM options provided in settings, add them to the object
    if (dkim.domainName && dkim.keySelector && dkim.privateKey) {
        emailParams.dkim = dkim
    }
    // Pass the new options back to the accounts function to be sent.
    return emailParams
}
```

Implement this during Meteor.startup() on the server side only. Be careful, this approach patches the package at runtime and should the package change, this can (easily) break.